# Is there any ascii inline editor I can use on my webserver?

Tags: text, editor, inline

Perhaps I'm over thinking this but I don't seem to be able to find a simple, trivial way to edit a file inline on a webpage.

I need to allow users to edit files stored on the system (linux router). One page per file is totally acceptable to me. 
This page would load the content of a text file in a text area, where at the bottom a Save button saves the content of the text into the file.

That's all. No security needed, no multi user, no login what so ever.

All the inline editor I can find out there are rich-text or WYSIWYG which I don't need and they actually might mess up the file content with unwanted tags.

Can anybody please point me in the right direction on how to implement such an editor? No ajax or funky things needed really, just a text area and a save button.

Comment: It's not that difficult to write something like that. What server/language?

Comment: it's running on a linux router that relay heavily on busybox, sh is the shell. I was thinking of javascript but it seems like it's not the best option to write on the filesystem (intentionally design not to, even though it's possible). It surprise me how many rich editor there are out there doing this but no simple ascii.